# The name 'TXTF' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm new to C# and currently I'm trying to make 2 simple textboxes for weather, one to have the temperature in Celsius, and the other textbox have the temperature in Fahrenheit, what I wanna do is make the user type the temperature in any textbox and the other will calculate and convert it like from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa,

but I keep getting errors:
"The name 'TXTF" does not exist in the current context"
"The name 'TXTC" does not exist in the current context"

here is my code:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MainWeb2
{
    public partial class Weather : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String C = TextBox1.Text;
            int TXTC = Int32.Parse(C);
            string TXTC1 = TXTC.ToString();
            TXTC = (TXTF - 32) * (5 / 9);
        }

        protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String F = TextBox2.Text;
            int TXTF = Int32.Parse(F);
            string TXTF1 = TXTF.ToString();
            TXTF = (TXTC) * (9 / 5) + 32;
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, the errors are gone but it doesn't seem to do any calculation when I type anything in any text box, what am I missing?

Comment: I get this error (Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string')  when I use `code`TextBox2.Text = TXTF`code` and `code` TextBox1.Text = TXTC;`code`

Comment: still isn't working, here is a link to my code now maybe I'm doing something wrong: https://codeshare.io/G6vyRk

Comment: Yeah you can type any number in any textboxes but nothing happens, numbers don't change.

Comment: I double clicked on the textboxes when I started and it was generated

Comment: Can you put a MessageBox into the TextChanged Callbacks and see if they actually get called. For Example `MessageBox.Show(TXTF.ToString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have looks rather fine. The ONLY part is you need to set both text boxes postback = true.

This setting for BOTH text boxes:

[image]

The only part missing is that you need to set both textboxes to fire a post back.

You could also I suppose put a button on the form, type in the value and hit the calculate button.

But, for both text boxes, you need to set postback = true.

And you code? Well, you could use this:

```
{
int TXTC;

TXTC = Int(TextBox1.Text);

TextBox2.Text = (TXTC - 32) * (5 / 9);
}
```

And for text box2, this:

```
{
int TXTC;

TXTC = Int(TextBox2.Text);

TextBox1.Text = (TXTC) * (9 / 5) + 32;
}
```

So the system will "cast" the data types to text for you. In fact, you could even do this, and it will work:

First one:

```
TextBox2.Text = (TextBox1.Text - 32) * (5 / 9);
```

and

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text * (9 / 5) + 32;
```

So unlike say native c++, .net does a LOT of automatic conversions for you.

And if you set the format of each text box to number (this setting)

[image]

Then users can ONLY type in numbers - and thus some additonal type checking is afforded by doing this. (users will ONLY be able to enter numbers - and thus you don't need all that type casting code.

All in all? Your code will and should work. Just missing the auto-post back setting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and effort, I've learned a lot from your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TXTC` and `TXTF` in the respective other `TextBox_Changed` CallBack, even tough it wasn't defined in that Function.

To fix that you would need to declare `TXTC` and `TXTF` outside of your functions so both of them can acces the values.

```cs
namespace MainWeb2 {
    public partial class Weather : System.Web.UI.Page {
        // Declare PlaceHolders for TextBoxes with default value of 1.
        int TXTC = 1;
        int TXTF = 1;

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ...
            Int32.TryParse(C, out TXTC);
            ...
        }

        protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ...
            Int32.TryParse(F, out TXTF);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```